# Animated Accordion

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript

Simple question with a lot of explanation.

I am trying to implement an accordion script in my Wordpress theme. I am using [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate) as a starting point but I have some problems getting it to work.

This is what I have done so far:

**This is how I load my scripts in functions.php:**

```
function alepscript() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'alepscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/alep.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'dotdotdot', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/dotdotdot.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.8.3', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'alepscript', 'dotdotdot' );
```

(alep.min.js is where I include the script)

**This is how I have added the script:**

```
(function($) {
  alert("Accordion script loaded");
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
})(jQuery);
```

I have added `(function($) {}` because I previously read that this is required for jQuery scripts in WordPress. I have also added `alert("Accordion script loaded");` just to be sure that the script is loading.

**CSS:**

```
button.accordion{background-color:#eee;color:#444;cursor:pointer;padding:18px;width:100%;border:none;text-align:left;outline:none;font-size:15px;transition:0.4s;}
button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover{background-color:#ddd;}
div.panel{padding:0 18px;background-color:white;max-height:0;overflow:hidden;transition:max-height 0.2s ease-out;}
```

**Markup:**

```
<h2>Animated Accordion</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons to open the collapsible content.</p>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

This is what I get:
[image]

If I try to click on one of the sections, nothing happens except an error in the console. I am not sure what this means or how to fix it, or if it is even the problem.

Comment: Hi, You should consider asking this on StackOverflow instead. This has nothing to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already loading JQuery, add the following `$('document')`:

```
(function($) {

$(window).load(function() { //lets wait for all to be loaded

  alert("Accordion script loaded");
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    }
  }

});

})(jQuery);
```

looks like `document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");` its returning `NULL` and you are trying to set the `style` property of it, this due to the script running too early, so nothing is found.

Comment: That might be... So what should I do?

Comment: i updated your JS code with $('document')

Comment: I tried your code. I still get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLButtonElement.s.(anonymous function).onclick`. I have made sure that the script is loaded last in the DOM.

Comment: ok, i updated with `$(window).load(function() {` is this a plain template you are using to show the markup?

Comment: @Arete after I tested your code, and using your script nothing happens, however if I used what is provided by David, then everything seems great. I think David pointed out what causes the problem.